# RepoDB with SQL Server's OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server, micro-orm

How can I access the contents of an OUTPUT clause with RepoDB, e.g.

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable(Name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES ('TheName')
```

Answer (score 0):

An DML with an `OUTPUT` clause looks to the client like a `SELECT`.  So it looks like [ExecuteQuery](https://repodb.net/operation/executequery) would be the correct API.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ExecuteScalar](https://repodb.net/operation/executescalar) extension method like below (only if you are inserting single row).

```
var result = connection.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO MyTable(Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Name);", new { Name = "TheName" });
```

Or using the typed-result.

```
var result = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>("INSERT INTO MyTable(Name) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Name);", new { Name = "TheName" });
```

If you are inserting multiple rows, please use the [ExecuteQuery](https://repodb.net/operation/executequery) method. The result would be a model (of type `IEnumerable<T>`).